# Django: Error 500 for favicon

Tags: django

On my local server, I'm getting the following error in terminal

```
[03/Oct/2011 22:49:19] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65893
```

In my `site_base.html`, I already have the following line:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/favicon.ico" />
```

What's causing this error and how can I make it stop?

Comment: 500 is a server side error, not a page cannot be found as is 404. Can you paste the full traceback so we can see the error?

Comment: I'm actually not getting any tracebacks locally. My page loads fine but admidst all the responses, that 500 error shows up.

Comment: Try setting DEBUG = True in your settings.py file.

Comment: DEBUG is set to True. But I'm not getting any tracebacks in the first place!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default lookup browsers do is `/favicon.ico`. However, since you specified the link the browser shouldn't be doing this. There's most likely a bug in the particular browser and version you're using responsible for sending the extra request, but that's beside the point.

You're getting a 500 error because that particular request is making it into the Django URL handling machinery, and whatever view is responding to, is choking on the provided arguments.

Check your urls.py and see which pattern(s) will accept the URL `/favicon.ico/`. Then, go into the corresponding views and see why it's causing it to choke, or alter the pattern such that it won't catch a URL like this, as it mostly likely shouldn't be in the first place.

Comment: My user app is using url patterns like this: `url(r'^(?P<user_slug>[^/]+)/$', 'user', name='user'),`. Does that mean I cant use this particular url pattern? Seems a bit extreme just to accommodate `/favicon.ico/`? Or perhaps an exact match exception that points to I'm not sure where?

Comment: Well, in general, it's not a good idea to have a nearly catch-all urlpattern at the root, but you can make it less conflicting by limiting it to actual slugs, e.g. `r'^(?P<user_slug>[\w-]+)/$'`. Then, something with a `.`, for example, won't be caught.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be 100% the issue that you're facing, but it's worth mentioning since you're using a custom favicon stored in your static folder.

In Django templating, you can [manage your static assets like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/):

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}">
```

No need to send a `{{ STATIC_URL }}` context variable into the template.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was appearing when I was trying to log in on the **admin** panel.

My error was:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'C' (0x43) at index 34
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
```

The problem was nested in my **urls.py:**

Suggestions from other users help me a little but in the end, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) was a game changer. Quote:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage # for `favicon` -> https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/django-favicon-adding/

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('project_foo\logos\media\favicon.ico')))]
```

I mean line: `path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('project_foo\logos\media\favicon.ico')))]`

**As the documentation stated quote:** *django.contrib.staticfiles collects static files from each of your applications (and any other places you specify) into a single location that can easily be served in production.*

In my case, I pointed out a file, not the location. Things were ok on the user page, but throw an error on the **admin** panel.

The solution in my case is:

```
`path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('project_foo\logos\media')))]`
```